# Apple AHT occasionally freezing MacBook Pro late 2011 OS X Lion

Tags: trackpad, apple-hardware-test

Running Apple Hardware Test (AHT) repeatedly on a late 2011 Macbook Pro over Wi-Fi (Option D).

Completes the process sometimes and says no problems but sometimes freezes (has done so during RAM testing portion as well as during logic board portion of the test). Should I consider both RAM and Logic board damaged or dismiss the freezing as likely the result of flakey Wi-Fi service?

I started running the test after reinstalling Lion over Wi-Fi because the trackpad had been responding weirdly.

Answer (score 1):

Using AHT over a flaky Wi-Fi connection shouldn't cause any freezing, because the required software is downloaded in entirety first, and then run.

If you've been experiencing issues with the trackpad too, you might have a hardware issue with your Mac. I would look into the issue further, maybe by having Apple look at it.